# JPA, Hibernate, OneToMany mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

JPA, Hibernate, OneToMany mapping problem

Given the parent:

```
@Entity
public class Discount {

@Id
private String id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String userName;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String iDocId;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Date creationTime;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String salesOrganization;

.........

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "discount")
private Set<DiscountConditionScale> conditionScales = new HashSet<DiscountConditionScale>();
.........
```

}

and the child:

```
@Entity
public class DiscountConditionScale {

@Id
@ManyToOne
private Discount discount;

private BigDecimal quantity;

private BigDecimal rate;
.......
```

}

I would like to have the key of DiscountConditionScale be (discount, rate, quantity). How do I achieve that?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you add the @Id annotation on the 3 attributes.

If your entity is more than a relation table (it holds additional attributes) I would advise to use an [EmbeddedId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html) instead

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need a constrain:

@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "discount", "rate", "quantity" })

But if you want the composite key too, map the keys in a diferent class and use it as the key for DiscountConditionSale:

http://j2eereference.com/2011/01/implementing-composit-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I added exactly this @UniqueConstraint but it has been ignored.

Comment: Of course it is... hibernate has to create the table for the constrains to be created or you create them manually.